# Python Pollard P-1 factorization

Tags: python, primes, prime-factoring, factorization

I'm trying to implement Pollard's P-1 factorization in Python.  Note that the Rho method has some answers but this p-1 is different and the best I can give you here about p-1 is the wiki and the Wolfram:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard's_p_%E2%88%92_1_algorithm

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Pollardp-1FactorizationMethod.html

This is factoring something from n but consistently does not find p. The np and sp are from numpy and scipy respectively.  So the built-in functions for sp.uint64 is an unsigned long 64 int (because of the size of the expected integers) and np.prod(p) is the cumulative product pi of the list p:

```
def pm1_attack(n,b):
  p = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17]; i=19; a=2
  while i<b:
    if is_prime(i,10): p.append(i)
    i+=2;
  k = sp.uint64(np.prod(p)); q = power2(a,k,n)
  g = euc_al_i((q-1),n)
  print "product pi: ",k
  print "q: ",q
  print "g: ",g
  #return a

print "pollard_pm1_attack(n,b): ",pollard_pm1_attack(n,2000)
```

Output does not find p:

```
Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 09:01:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
p = 1300199 
q = 2063507 

euler_totient = 2682966374188 

common n = 2682969737893 


public key e = 1588051820871 

secret key d = 2410616084843 

cleartext message = test 

encoded message = 1489995542681 

decoded message = test 

check_rsa = Successful encryption and decrytion. Message is authenticated. 

pollard_pm1_attack(n,b):  product pi:  18446744073460481730
q:  2391570546599
g:  1
None
>>>
```

I'm learning Python so it may be some simple mistake.  The power2() function uses exponentiation by squaring and is basically a super-charged pow() for very large integers.  The euc_al_i() is just the gcd.  You can use whatever gcd() you like, but since I'm learning I wanted to make these myself.

I'm trying to find out what went so horribly wrong here that it doesn't find p from even relatively small n (as small as 20 bit-length).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know what *np.prod* and *sp.uint64* do, but I can tell you about the *p* - 1 algorithm, which was invented by John Pollard in 1974.

Pollard's algorithm is based on Fermat's Little Theorem *a* ^ *p* == *a* (mod *p*), which when *a* != 0 can be stated *a* ^ (*p* - 1) == 1 (mod *p*) by dividing *a* through the expression. As a consequence, if *p* - 1 divides *m*, then *p* divides gcd(2^*m* - 1, *n*). Pollard's *p* - 1 algorithm computes *m* as the least common multiple of the integers less than a bound *b*, so that if all the factors of *p* - 1 are less than *b*, then gcd(2 ^ lcm(1..*b*) - 1, *n*) is a factor of *n*. The least common multiple is computed by multiplying primes less than *b* by their multiplicities less than *b*:

```
function pminus1(n, b)
    c := 2
    for p in primes(b)
        pp := p
        while pp < b
            c := powerMod(c, p, n)
            pp := pp * p
    g := gcd(c-1, n)
    if 1 < g < n return g
    error "factorization failed"
```

An optional second stage searches for a "large prime" between *b1* and *b2* that combines with the least common multiple of the first stage to find a factor. The second stage requires only a modular multiplication for each prime rather than a modular exponentiation, making it quite fast, and the second-stage gcds can be computed in batches. The cache is small but important to the efficiency of the function.

```
function pminus1(n, b1, b2)
    c := 2
    for p in primes(b1)
        pp := p
        while pp < b
            c := powerMod(c, p, n)
            pp := pp * p
    g := gcd(c-1, n)
    if 1 < g < n return g
    k := 0
    for q in primes(b1, b2)
        d := q - p
        if d is not in cache
            x := powerMod(c, d, n)
            store d, x in cache
        c := (c * x(d)) % n
        p := q
        k := k + 1
        if k % 100 == 0
            g := gcd(c-1, n)
            if 1 < g < n return g
    g := gcd(c-1, n)
    if 1 < g < n return g
    error "factorization failed"
```

It is possible that Pollard's *p* - 1 method may fail to find a factor of *n*; it depends on the factorization of *n* - 1 and the bounds you have chosen. The way to check is to factor *n* - 1 yourself, then call Pollard's method with a *b* that is larger than the largest factor of *n* - 1. For instance, if you want to factor *n* = 87463 = 149 * 587, note that *n* - 1 = 87462 = 2 * 3 * 3 * 43 * 113, so call the one-stage algorithm with *b* = 120 or the two-stage algorithm with *b1* = 50 and *b2* = 120 and see if you find a factor.

I discuss Pollard's *p* - 1 factorization algorithm, along with several other factorization algorithms, at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com). I also give there implementations of the powerMod and gcd functions, in case you are having trouble with your implementations of those functions. And I wrote a simple implementation of the single-stage algorithm, in Python, at http://ideone.com/wdyjxK.

Comment: If you used np.prod to compute the product of the primes less than the current bound, then the problem is that it doesn't consider the multiplicities of the primes. For instance, with 87463, the factorization of n-1 includes 3^2, but you only included one factor of 3 in your calculation of the least common multiple.

Comment: Brilliant! This cleared up some questions I was having about the algorithm itself. The pseudo-code and example code really drove the point home. I edited to explain about the built-in np and sp functions you weren't sure about. I'm not sure where I was going wrong though...  Tried yours on n=2867396366521 and got this error --- sieve = [True] * n
OverflowError: cannot fit 'long' into an index-sized integer --- but the basic algorithm is what's important here and your explanation fixed what I missed so it's just a matter of handling the very large int's which is just a technical issue.

Comment: @stackuser: To factor n = 2867396366521 you will need b1=50 and b2=b1*10^6, which means that p-1 is not the algorithm of choice for factoring n. Try Pollard's rho algorithm. In general, you probably want to try trial division to 1000 first, to get the low-hanging fruit, then a million steps of Pollard's rho algorithm as the workhorse of your factoring function, followed by Pollard's p-1 algorithm, which  might find a lucky factor when n-1 is smooth over a small bound. After that elliptic curves or quadratic sieve. The key is to use the appropriate factoring method at each step.

Comment: One question I have: the Wikipedia page for the algorithm says that if we end up with N after taking the GCD, then we should decrease the bound (as it means all factors are powersmooth, so we need to home in on one that isn't). But if we use modular exponentiation to calculate the product, don't we lose the ability to do that? Or does `c == 0` in this case?

Comment: @Thomas: Modular exponentiation has nothing to do with losing any ability. And you should not set `c = 0` because then everything will always be zero. If the factor you find is composite, rerun the algorithm with the predicate `k % 100 == 0` changed so that the gcd is computed more often, say `k % 10 == 0`. This should be very infrequent because usually the factors found in the second stage are widely separated.

Comment: @user448810 I meant the final value of `c`, not its initial value. What I was saying is that since the running value of `c` is reduced modulo `n` each time, `gcd(c - 1, n)` cannot possibly equal `n`, which Wikipedia said was a sign that every `p - 1` of `n` was smooth. But thanks for your explanations, that makes sense.

Comment: @user448810 can you explain what the cache does and why it's needed?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a two stage version implemented in python.

```
from math import gcd, log

def pminus1(n, B1, B2):
    log_B1 = log(B1)
    M = 1
    primes = prime_sieve()
    for p in primes:
        if p > B1:
            break
        M *= p**int(log_B1/log(p))
    M = pow(2, M, n)
    g = gcd(M-1, n)
    if 1 < g < n:
        return True
    if g == n:
        return False

    # Start part 2.
    cache = {0:M}
    S = (M*M) % n
    for d in range(2, int(log(B2)**2), 2):
        cache[d] = cache[d-2] * S) % n

    HQ = M
    for k, q in enumerate(primes):
        if q > B2:
            break
        d = q - p
        HQ = (HQ * cache[d]) % n
        M = (M * (HQ-1)) % n
        p = q
        if k % 200 == 0:
            if 1 < gcd(M, n) < n:
                return True
    return 1 < gcd(M, n) < n
```

Comment: I think this comment is on the wrong question but, yeah, i think my edit may be python 3+, but honestly does anyone write things in 2.7 anymore?

Comment: it is on the wrong question because that's where I could reach you. :)

Comment: @OscarSmith I'm trying to understand two stage P-1. Could you please explain how your code works? For example what does a cache or logarithm have anything to do with it? I asked a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3418562/what-benefits-does-the-two-stage-variant-of-pollards-p-1-have-how-is-it-differ).

Comment: The cache here stores powers of S mod n, since lots are needed, and they are expensive. The log is there because that's how many powers are needed.

Comment: @OscarSmith I think this line has a typo `cache[d] = cache[d-2] * S) % n`

Comment: It does. My code review post with similar code is correct though